# Return array class

Tags: java, arrays, return

I have a question! I don`t know How can I retur the array? I want to use get and set.

```
 TypeOfWater[] waters = returnTypes1();

public String[] getTypeOfWater()
{
    return waters;//How can I rerutn array???
}


private static TypeOfWater[] returnTypes1()
{
    TypeOfWater[] type = new TypeOfWater[4];
    type[0] = new TypeOfWater();
    type[0].name = "1)Fanta";
    type[0].cost = 11;

    type[1] = new TypeOfWater();
    type[1].name = "2)Coca";
    type[1].cost = 12;

    type[2] = new TypeOfWater();
    type[2].name = "3)Sprite";
    type[2].cost = 14;

    type[3] = new TypeOfWater();
    type[3].name = "4)Orange juice";
    type[3].cost = 22;

    return type;
}
```

Please, help me. I am new at java programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
public String[] getTypeOfWater()
{
    return waters;//How can I rerutn array???
}
```

for

```
public TypeOfWater[] getTypeOfWater()
{
    return waters;//How can I rerutn array???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your return is not the good!

Water is TypeOfWater[] and your getTypeOfWater method return a String[]

So, try to change your String[] by a TypeOfWater[]

Answer (score 0):

The return data type of `getTypeOfWater()` is incorrect. It's set to return `String[]` when it should be returning `TypeOfWater[]`

`getTypeOfWater()` is also a misleading function name if you're trying to return the array itself. If that's the case, the function should be renamed.